# C++ not recognize my changes in object.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I use visual studio 2019 community edition. I'm trying to make a basic OpenGL withdrawing 3d objects in perspective. Whatever. The problem is when I change anything and run, the program doesn't display that change unless i "Rebuild Solution".example.

object.cpp

```
std::cout<< "PosX"<<std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout<< "PosX1"<<std::endl;
```

when I run again, I get old output "PosX", not the new one.

I have these files on my project

```
main.cpp
header.h
Object.cpp
Puller.cpp
Cube.cpp
Cyclinder.cpp
```

I'm including all other class files within the header.h with safeguard(`#ifndef #define class example #endif`)
if you want I can provide the code. Thx for your time.

i dont have other classes header file. Only .cpp file

Object.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

#ifndef OBJECT_CPP
#define OBJECT_CPP

class Object
{
public:
    GLfloat matrixMV[16];
    vec3 Cordinates;
    vec3 Scale;
    vec4r Rotate;

    Object()
    {
    };

    Object(vec3 _Cordinates, vec3 _Scale = vec3(1, 1, 1), vec4r _Rotate = vec4r(0, 0, 0, 0)) : Cordinates(_Cordinates),
                                                                                               Scale(_Scale),
                                                                                               Rotate(_Rotate)
    {
    };

    virtual void move(vec2 direction)
    {
        Cordinates.x += direction.x;
        Cordinates.y += direction.y;
    };
};
#endif
```

header.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "GL/glut.h"

struct vec3
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;

    vec3(GLfloat _x = 0, GLfloat _y = 0, GLfloat _z = 0)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
};

struct vec2
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;

    vec2(GLfloat _x = 0, GLfloat _y = 0)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
};

struct vec4r
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
    GLfloat radiant;

    vec4r(GLfloat _x = 0, GLfloat _y = 0, GLfloat _z = 0, GLfloat _radiant = 0) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), radiant(_radiant)
    {
    };
};

const double PI = 3.1415927;

#include "Object.cpp"
#include "Puller.cpp"
#include "Cube.cpp"
#include "Cyclinder.cpp"
#include "TrianglePrism.cpp"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <cstdint>


char wTitle[] = "3D PinPon";

GLfloat aspect = 0;
GLsizei _height;
GLsizei _width;
unsigned int id;
/* PREDEFINATION */
void display();

GLdouble _angle = 0.0;
vec3 rotate = vec3();


Cube block;
Cyclinder RightCylinder;
Cyclinder LeftCylinder;
Cube littlecube;
TrianglePrism my_prism;
Puller my_puller;


void initGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Set background color to black and opaque
    glClearDepth(1.0); // Set background depth to farthest
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing for z-culling
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); // Set the type of depth-test
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // Enable smooth shading
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Nice perspective corrections
}

void reshape(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    // GLsizei for non-negative integer
    _height = height;
    _width = width; // Compute aspect ratio of the new window
    if (height == 0) height = 1; // To prevent divide by 0
    aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

    // Set the viewport to cover the new window
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Set the aspect ratio of the clipping volume to match the viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // To operate on the Projection matrix
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset
    // Enable perspective projection with fovy, aspect, zNear and zFar
    gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0);
    //glOrtho(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
}

void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 27)
        exit(0);
}

void processSpecialKeys(int key, int xx, int yy)
{
    float fraction = 0.1;
    float speed = 0.05f;
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        rotate = vec3(rotate.x > 0 ? rotate.x - 0.1f : 0, rotate.y < 1 ? rotate.y + 0.1f : 1,
                      rotate.z > 0 ? rotate.z - 0.1f : 0);
        _angle -= 10;
        block.move(vec2(-1 * speed, 0));
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        rotate = vec3(rotate.x > 0 ? rotate.x - 0.1f : 0, rotate.y < 1 ? rotate.y + 0.1f : 1,
                      rotate.z > 0 ? rotate.z - 0.1f : 0);
        _angle += 10;
        block.move(vec2(1 * speed, 0));
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        rotate = vec3(rotate.x < 1 ? rotate.x + 0.1f : 1, rotate.y > 0 ? rotate.y - 0.1f : 0, 0);
        _angle -= 10;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        rotate = vec3(rotate.x < 1 ? rotate.x + 0.1f : 1, rotate.y > 0 ? rotate.y - 0.1f : 0, 0);
        _angle += 10;

        break;
    }
}

void demo_menu(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case 1:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 2:
        glutIdleFunc(display);
        break;
    case 3:
        glutIdleFunc(nullptr);
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear color and depth buffers
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // To operate on model-view matrix



    littlecube.render();
    RightCylinder.render();
    LeftCylinder.render();
    my_prism.render();
    my_puller.render();
    block.render();
    //std::cout << LeftCylinder.matrixMV[12] << std::endl;


    glutSwapBuffers(); // Swap the front and back frame buffers (double buffering)
}

void InitObjects()
{
    my_puller = Puller(vec3(-1.95, -2.9, -7.0),vec3(1,1,1),vec4r());
    block = Cube(0.2, vec3(-0.03, -2.35, 0), vec3(3, 1, 1),my_puller);
    littlecube = Cube(0.3, vec3(0, 1, 0));
    RightCylinder = Cyclinder(0.2, 0.5f, 255, 160, 100, vec3(0.8, 0, -6), false);
    LeftCylinder = Cyclinder(0.3, 0.3f, 255, 160, 100, vec3(-0.8, 0, -6), true);
    my_prism = TrianglePrism(vec3(0, 0, -7), vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3), vec4r(0.2, 0, 0, 20));

}

void secondDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear color and depth buffers
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // To operate on model-view matrix
    glutSwapBuffers(); // Swap the front and back frame buffers (double buffering)
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitObjects();
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); // Enable double buffered mode
    glutInitWindowSize(480, 720); // Set the window's initial width & height
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner

    //id = glutCreateWindow("second window");
    //glutSetWindow(id);
    //glutCreateMenu(demo_menu);
    //glutAddMenuEntry("quit", 1);
    //glutAddMenuEntry("start rotation", 2);
    //glutAddMenuEntry("stop rotation", 3);
    //glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
    //glutDisplayFunc(secondDisplay);
    //glutIdleFunc(secondDisplay);


    glutCreateWindow(wTitle); // Create window with the given title
    glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register callback handler for window re-paint event
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); // Register callback handler for window re-size event
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
    glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);
    initGL(); // Our own OpenGL initialization
    glutMainLoop(); // Enter the infinite event-processing loop
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right click on the file, does it contain "Exclude from build" or something like that?

Comment: Please provide more information about the class, project and etc.

Comment: Fyi, `object.h` isn't even in the list of files you say are in your project. Post a *real* [mcve].

Comment: sounds like a really bad idea to just put ``cout << stuff`` in a header

Comment: @WhozCraig i had no other choice to ask here. sorry. and I think i tried my best to provide more detail. :P

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis no. Unfortunately. it's not exluded. thx for you answer thou :;)

Comment: Do you really have `#include "Object.cpp"` and similar in your code? You should never include a `.cpp`

Comment: This is not a C++ but build manager issue. Some cache data has been corrupted and  `object.cpp` was not recompiled so/or old object file is used during linking process. Since you are using visual studio and issue is constantly reproducible (you have to do rebuilds) something get broken in project file. I'm guessing that your project has multiple solutions and some dependency between them is broken. Do you have circular dependency between solutions?

Comment: @MarekR thx for your answer. But no i have 1 solution. How can i provide more details about Build manager problem ?

Comment: I think part of your problem is including cpp files.

Comment: `Object.cpp` should be named `Object.h` giving it a `.cpp` extension could cause issues with build management.

Comment: I agree with @drescherjm this is definitely part of the problem and this is what confused Visual Studio what are dependencies between files. "Object.cpp" is not listed as a source so when it changes VS doesn't know that to handle that change "main.cpp" should be recompiled.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is when I change anything and run, the program doesn't display that change unless i "Rebuild Solution"

When I was first writing this answer, the code from the [earlier version of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56169230/revisions) indicated that the object file can't be consumed by the linker with the changes you made until it's been rebuilt--but since the files included were never linked correctly, you'd never see the changes.

Your issue lies in basic project organization.

For starters, look at the bottom of your header file and how you are organizing your includes. Remove this section from your header file:

```
#include "Object.cpp"
#include "Puller.cpp"
#include "Cube.cpp"
#include "Cyclinder.cpp"
#include "TrianglePrism.cpp"
```

While including `*.cpp` files from other `*.cpp` files is legal C++, it's not really adhering to the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Source files (`*.cpp`) should include header files, not the other way around.

Header files should contain things like class declarations, and the source files contain their respective implementations.

If you want to have a single header file, that's fine. It should have something like this:

header.h

```
#ifndef MYPROJECT_HEADER_H
#define MYPROJECT_HEADER_H

// all your header specifications

#endif
```

Then, all your `*.cpp` files include `header.h`.

I don't understand what you are trying to do by organizing your project in this way. If you are going for a traditional, object-oriented approach to development, you would create your class declarations in header files and then include those header files in any `*.cpp` file where you want to manipulate some instance of said class.

Your `main.cpp` file should be the glue that binds everything together. Your other `*.cpp` files should be the implementation of the classes you are defining in the other `*.h` files.

Comment: Actually you can have files with some header files and files with no header files. It's perfectly fine. The linker can link up a bunch of source files and handle `extern` calls from a few header files just fine.

Comment: sorry man wrong alarm. :/ it's still same problem even if i change "header.h" to "header.cpp"

Comment: You probably want to do a clean build. Maybe totally delete the Debug / Release folders.

Comment: @RepiatX, header should be a `.h` file.

`main.cpp` should `#include<header.h>`

`header.h` is fine

`Object.cpp` should `#include <header.h>`

`Puller.cpp` should `#include <header.h>`

`Cube.cpp` should `#include <header.h>`

`Cyclinder.cpp` should `#include <header.h>`


Your header files are your specifications, and your source files are your implementations.

Comment: @JesseLawson Thx man for your hard work. What im tryin to accomplish... uhm. i just want to divide my main file so easy to read. :)  [link](https://yadi.sk/d/Vgd9_gFImxHeBQ) these files are my project files. all of them.